Does the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n q^{n(n+1)}\cos((2n+1)z)$, related to the Jacobi theta function, have a name or simple characterization?
This is primarily a terminology question. The sum
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n q^{n(n+1)}\cos((2n+1)z)$$
doesn't seem to be a simple transformation of any of the Jacobi theta functions despite its apparent similarity. I can express it as an integral, as the Hilbert transformation of the first Jacobi theta function, but is there a simpler name (perhaps as part of some parametrized family) or characterization for it?

"Partial Theta Function" is a term that is used for such things.
